# Should it be "Late policy" or "lateness policy"?

Tags: word-usage, noun-phrases

I am writing a paper that discusses different policies for accepting assignments after the nominal deadlines. Should I refer to it as a "late policy" or "lateness policy"?

Here is a sample sentence:

> Figure 2 shows students' ratings of different late/lateness policies.

Comment: You should refer to it as whatever the teacher involved calls it. It's their policy and they get to name it.

Comment: @JohnLawler, the OP made it clear that she is writing about different policies of this kind, not about a particular one. As different policies of this kind may have different names, it is not unreasonable to wonder what the best generic term for them is.

Comment: @JohnLawler I am the teacher.

Comment: Then you get to decide who reads it, what they need to know, and what to call it. You know local conventions and audience much better than anybody else. The teacher is, after all, the boss.

Comment: "lateness policy" sounds better as it's clearly a policy on lateness; "late policy" sounds like it could be a delayed policy and may confuse some. However I think "late form/slip", "late policy", etc, are also common uses, so neither is wrong.

Comment: In that both are ambiguous - is it a policy about overdue assignments, or students who show up late to class - I'd opt for "late work policy"

Comment: If I had to choose between the two, I'd say "lateness policy" rather than "late policy" because "late policy" sounds like you're saying the policy itself is recent, behind schedule, or somehow dead. That said, I don't like "lateness policy," either, because when I read it, I immediately thought you were referring to a tardiness policy (i.e., students arriving late). It wasn't until I read your details that I realized you were talking about something else. With that in mind, what I'd say and what I've seen professors write on their syllabi is "late homework policy" or "late assignment policy."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is late here is the submission of the assignments that the policies are about. The policies themselves are not late; one would hope that they are promulgated well ahead of the time when they are likely to be needed.

Does that mean that calling them *late policies* is wrong? Some people will say that it is, using the argument formulated in the preceding paragraph. Others will defend it by saying that it is a case of a **transferred epithet**: when something like 'the policy about late submission of assignments' is shortened, the crucial adjective *late* is transferred from *submission* to *policy*, and we get *the late policy*. Transferred epithets are a common linguistic phenomenon, and they are not inherently wrong.

It can thus be argued that either *late policy* or *lateness policy* would be OK, and that the choice is a matter of the writer's preference. However, even though transferred epithets are not inherently wrong, they tend to annoy linguistically sensitive people (unless the transferred epithet is **very** well established, which is not the case with *late policy*). Because of that, *lateness policy*, which is not going to rub anyone the wrong way, is a safer choice.